# How to create Adhoc network in VMWare-virtualised Windows 7 and join with other windows 7 users?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, vmware-fusion, ad-hoc-network

I'm just curious if (and if yes, how) it is possible to create a wireless ad-hoc network in a VMWare-virtualised Windows 7 and after that join with other Windows-7-based PCs?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a wireless adaptor to the guest from networking settings wouldn't work since this will be virtualised as an ethernet card. This could work if you use a USB wireless adaptor, but then you should give exclusive access to the virtual machine. That means you cannot use the same adaptor in both the guest OS and the host. If the host is a laptop, say, it can be connected wirelessly using its internal wireless adaptor, while the guest will use the USB wireless adaptor and both will have wireless access to the same or different wireless network. If you need to connect the guest ot an ad hoc wireless network with other computers, then this makes sense. But if you want to connect the guest with the host, then you can do it directly using the relevant virtual adaptor and appropriate settings so that either excange data but guest has no internet access, or they exchange data and guest has internet access.

Answer (score 0):

@spapakons wall of text answer is correct, but I feel wit lacks one point of crucial background.

In order to make a wireless ad-hoc network you need a wireless card.

A WMware-fusion guest has access to mostly virtual hardware. Repeat **virtual**. That included a fake-network card which can be used to route traffic to whatever the host is using,

Since a guest does not have native access to a Wirelessnetwork you cannot just use a guest to create a wireless ad-hoc network.

What you can do it PCI-e passthough a device under vmware server or ESI, or USB-passthough a USB based device with vmware-player/workstation/fusion. Which leads us to the solution; Add a wireless USB device accessible only to the win7 guest.